# php - Use proxy pac file with curl?

Tags: php, curl, proxy, pac

Is there a way to use a proxy pac file with curl in php? I'd like my web server to be able to access external web pages through my company's proxy, but rather than a static IP+port, a pac file is used. Can I do this in curl?